# NodeJS exec can't find MachineGuid from registry using powershell cmdlet

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, registry, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to obtain the MachineGuid through NodeJS using `child_process.exec` with cmdlet `Get-ItemPropertyValue`

```
const command = "Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Cryptography' -Name MachineGuid"
const options = { shell: 'powershell.exe' }
const id = execSync(command, options).toString()
```

This displays an error that the property MachineGuid is not part of the key.

The command works with different keys and using `Get-ItemProperty` will result an empty string for `Cryptography`, but gives correct results for something like `COM3`
Also, when running through a regular powershell and not inside a node shell, it will actually return the MachineGuid as expected.
Using `Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Cryptography'` in node returns `True\r\n` so apparently the key can be found but not the values

**Alternatives considered:**

- disable/enable group policy for editing registry (no difference)
- running as administrator (no difference)
- `using reg.exe`, but this might be disabled by administrator as group policy (which is why i try to use this approach in the first place)
- [node-machine-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-machine-id) package, but that also uses `reg.exe` under the hood
- [regedit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regedit) package, but this won't display any values for cryptography as well

pretty lost here and could not find anything useful through googling, so wondering if someone has an idea why it doesn't work and how to work around it

Answer (score 0):

you can try this npm package written by me - [@camol/winreg-rs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@camol/winreg-rs)

```js
const { JsRegistry } = require("@camol/winreg-rs");

const registry = new JsRegistry('HKLM');

const value = registry.getKeyValue("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", "MachineGuid")

console.log({value})
```